# Swift JSON Parse on dynamic JSON Structure

Tags: json, swift5

I'm trying to parse a JSON received from my server, but for some parts the structure is dynamic and I'm not able to extract correctly data.

Here is the JSON Structure I receive:

```
{"config":[{"param1":"62","period":"1","batt":"100%","mode":"ON","param2":"21.4"}],"alarms":[{"1":"433C3E64500B57B2"},{"2":"433C3E64500B57C2"},{"3":"803C3E64Cf0A5AD2"},{"4":"Eb503E64Af0858B1"},{"5":"Df513E64Eb0759C1"},{"6":"7E543E64040959D1"},{"nb_alarms":"5"}]}
```

I'm using the following Codable Structure

```
struct DataRetrieved: Codable {
    let config: [ContentRetrieved]
    let alarms: [AlarmsRetrieved]?
}

struct ContentRetrieved: Codable {
    let param1: String
    let period: String
    let batt: String
    let mode: String
    let param2: String
}

struct AlarmsRetrieved: Codable {
    let alarms: [String]
    let nb_alarms: String
}
```

And I'm parsing the JSON like this:

```
let jHistory = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataRetrieved.self, from: (DataHistory?.data(using: .utf8))!)
print("conf period \(jHistory.config[0].period)")

print("nb of alarms \(jHistory.alarms![0].nb_alarms!)")
```

I can extract any data from config JSONArray but not from alarms JSONArray (in that cat I have an error "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value").

the alarm JSONArray is dynamic and may contain hundreds of items, which can be known by retrieving nb_alarms value.
I would need to be able to parse each item of alarms and extract values (the order is important, this is the reason why there is a number for each alarms item).

It makes sense as the alarms JSONArray is getting multiple items "1", "2",...,"nb_alarms" and I cannot insert it as a Codable structure.

Si I tried to change the Codable structure like this:

```
struct DataRetrieved: Codable {
    let config: [ContentRetrieved]
    let alarms: [String]
}
```

but I get the following error while parsing alarms part:

> Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead

any idea how I can extract alarms JSONArray content ?

Comment: If this is ***your server*** a better solution is to send reliable static data. Another way is to decode `AlarmsRetrieved` as `[[String:String]]`.

Comment: I tired as well, I have the following error "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, String> but found an array instead"

Comment: `[[String:String]]` **is** an array, note the double brackets.

Comment: oops missed a bracket....works better now, thanks !